# Python CSV Comparison with multiplication

Tags: python, csv, import, percentage, multiplication

I want to double-check my logic on how to put this together in Python, so examples are appreciated.

I need to compare 2 CSV files (same format exactly with 2 rows and 6 columns) and provide the difference.

I need to pull both in and multiply row 2, columns 2-6 by specific values (5), total them separately, and then compare with each other (CSV2 total/CSV1 total), and present in a percentage format.

import csv and reader seem like the way to go, but the tricky part for me has been pulling it into a list I can multiply against different values (or should I use a collection?), and then comparing the two in the most concise/efficient manner.

Code update (based on 2nd answer- was great, thanks! but now encountering error with calling my row values integers):

```
import csv
file1 = open('csv1.csv', 'rb')
csv1 = csv.DictReader(file1)

file2 = open('csv2.csv', 'rb')
csv2 = csv.DictReader(file2)


myList = csv2.fieldnames
myList.append('Difference')

outFile = open('outFilename.csv', 'wb')
outCsv = csv.DictWriter(outFile, myList)

file1Dict = dict()
file2Dict = dict()

for row in file1:
    file1Dict[row['key value']]['Total1'] = {'Total1':(int(row[1]) * .75 + int(row[2]) * 2.25 + int(row[3]) * 3.5 + int(row[4]) * 5 + int(row[5]) * 25)}

for row in file2:
    file2Dict[row['key value']]['Total2'] = {'Total2':(int(row[1]) * .75, int(row[2]) * 2.25, int(row[3]) * 3.5, int(row[4]) * 5, int(row[5]) * 25)}

outFile.writeheader()

for stuff in file1Dict:
    file1Dict[stuff]['Difference'] = str(int(int(file1Dict[stuff]['Total2']) / int(file1Dict[stuff]['Total1'])) * 100) + '\%'
    outFile.writerow(file1Dict[stuff])

print 'difference'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why don't you show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: It would also be nice to see the example input and the output you are expecting.

Comment: This might help you, http://help.hackshackers.com/questions/whats-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-large-csvs-against-each-other/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Python Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and the built-in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) function, since this will be very efficient and put it into a rectangular form where any kind of math operations are trivial to apply and easy to compare across two different imported data sets.

Note that after importing `pandas`, there is a global level `read_csv`, called just as `pandas.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv")` rather than needing to go through `io.parsers` as in the linked doc page above.

There's nothing wrong with doing this through standard modules; I just think if you plan to do aggregate or broadcasted math operations, the rectangular array provided by Pandas that uses the efficient NumPy math operations is the best choice.

Comment: Pandas seems cool, though I'm getting this error (v 2.7 of both python and Pandas): "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/budget", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 25, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:37082)
ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser"

Comment: That seems specific to your system, I'm using Python 2.7.3 (also, there is no version 2.7 of Pandas, so I'm not sure what version you're referring to.. do you mean 0.2.7? If so, that's extremely old and it's unlikely you're using it because you'd actually have to go way out of your way to get a version that old). For me, `dateutil.parser` is a valid module that I can import.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm sure I just have the wrong version. :) Excited to explore pandas more.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
file1 = open('filename1.csv', 'rb')
csv1 = csv.DictReader(file1)

file2 = open('filename2.csv', 'rb')
csv2 = csv.DictReader(file2)


myList = csv2.fieldnames
myList.append('Total1','Total2', 'Difference')

outFile = open('outFilename.csv', 'wb')
outCsv = csv.DictWriter(outFile, myList)

file1Dict = dict()
file2Dict = dict()

for rows in file1:
    file1Dict[rows['key value']] = {rows[0], rows[1], 'Total1':int(rows[1]) * 5}

for rows in file2:
    file1Dict[rows['key value']]['Total2'] = {'Total2':int(rows[1]) * 5}

outFile.writeheader()

for stuff in file1Dict:
    file1Dict[stuff]['Difference'] = str(int(int(file1Dict[stuff]['Total2']) / int(file1Dict[stuff]['Total1'])) * 100) + '\%'
    outFile.writerow(file1Dict[stuff])
```

Just a quick put together of what you described, without non standard modules.

Comment: Thanks! I actually switched course to what you suggested because I really liked it, with some updates (each number needs to be multiplied by a different value). I'm now getting the error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'" when I should be hitting integers within the csv. Thoughts? Code updated above.